# How to alias a starred group of columns in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Consider:

- table `users` with column `id`,
- table `features`, with columns `id`, `day`, `x`, `y`, and `z`.

My query is:

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  a.* EXCEPT(id, day),
  b.* EXCEPT(id, day)
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN features AS a
    ON users.id = a.id
    AND a.day = DATE("2021-04-14")
  LEFT JOIN features AS b
    ON users.id = b.id
    AND b.day = DATE("2020-01-01")
```

And it returns the following columns:

```
id | x | y | z | x_1 | y_2 | z_3
--------------------------------
...
```

Is there any way to alias the columns with a custom suffix? Something like:

```
SELECT
  a.* AS *_from_a,
  b.* AS *_from_b
```

To obtain:

```
id | x_from_a | y_from_a | z_from_a | x_from_b | y_from_b | z_from_b
--------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Comment: This isn't possible in SQL as far as I know, but in any case you generally wouldn't want to do this.  What happens if columns happen to be removed/added?  Your result set would totally change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is answer on updated question:

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(id, day) FROM UNNEST([a])) AS from_a,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(id, day) FROM UNNEST([b])) AS from_b,
FROM
  users
  LEFT JOIN features AS a
    ON users.id = a.id
    AND a.day = DATE("2021-04-14")
  LEFT JOIN features AS b
    ON users.id = b.id
    AND b.day = DATE("2020-01-01")
```

with output  as

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on the impact to performance for these changes?

Comment: don't see any performance (or other) problem related to above approach :o)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the option I can think of (not exactly the way you expect - but I think will meet your goal)

```
SELECT
  a as from_a,
  b as from_b
FROM
  mytable AS a,
  mytable AS b
```

will return below

[image]

Comment: This is certainly useful! I do have a problem in that `mytable` is actually joining onto a main table though, so I need `EXCEPT` to remove the join key: `SELECT maintable.*, a.* EXCEPT(id), b.* EXCEPT(id) FROM maintable LEFT JOIN mytable AS a USING id LEFT JOIN mytable AS b USING id`. Maybe I should add this to the original post...

Comment: it is not appreciated here on SO when you change your question after answer already posted :o( i will check new updated question - but in future please do not do this if possible :o)

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Thanks anyway for checking again!